# Форма редактирования php

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Подскажите,какую-либо **библиотеку** для php (желательно с github) или вообще как можно сделать примерно такое для формы, чтобы можно было вставлять текст, шрифты менять прямо в форме, и потом отображалось это все.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конкретно на скриншоте изображён https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown

Comment: Это называется WYSIWYG HTML Editor, в интернете найдете тот которым вам понравится.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что приходит в голову - это TinyMCE, но она выглядит несколько иначе. В сети куча инструкций как она прикручивается к Laravel. Например гугл нашел [эту](http://modx.ws/uroki/sozdanie-bloga-na-laravel/tinymce-user-profile-laravel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам подойдет [Imperavi](https://imperavi.com/redactor/). Примерно так он выглядит после настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]